# MySQL: JOIN sum of multiple values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that calculates an invoice from table `invoice`. This invoice has taxes associated to it located in `tax_recv` table. The `tax_recv` will have multiple rows that are tied to an invoice in `invoice` table.

I have a query that calculates 12 months worth of invoices and orders them by their corresponding date. Here is the query:

```
SELECT 
    invoice_amount + late_fee + SUM(c.tax) AS amount, tollfree_json, date_generated 
FROM 
    invoices as i 
LEFT JOIN 
    csi_tax_recv as c 
ON 
    c.invoice_number = i.id 
WHERE 
    DATE_FORMAT(date_generated,'%Y-%m') < DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m') 
AND 
    DATE_FORMAT(date_generated,'%Y-%m') >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 12 MONTH,'%Y-%m') 
ORDER BY 
    date_generated
```

The only problem with this query, is it is only returning one row? Not sure exactly why. The minute I remove the left join and the SUM(c.tax) (which is what I think is causing the issue), the query works great.

The end result should look like this:

```
invoice_amount + total_taxes_for_invoices,  tollfree_json, date_generated
```

Cheers.

Comment: Looks like you're missing a GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As people said, you need to group by the fields you want to get the sum of the taxes and make calculations with that sum, something like this:

```
   SELECT
        i.tollfree_json,
        i.date_generated,
        (i.invoice_amount + i.late_fee + SUM(c.tax)) AS amount

    FROM
        invoices as i JOIN csi_tax_recv as c ON i.id = c.invoice_number

    WHERE
        DATE_FORMAT(date_generated,'%Y-%m') < DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m')
    AND
        DATE_FORMAT(date_generated,'%Y-%m') >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 12 MONTH,'%Y-%m')

    GROUP BY
        i.tollfree_json,
        i.date_generated

    ORDER BY
        i.date_generated
```

With this query, you will get the sum of the taxes aggregated by every `tollfree_json` and `date_generated` combination, and you can add the invoice_amount and late_fee to that sum, if this is what you looked for.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    invoice_amount + late_fee + SUM(c.tax) AS amount, tollfree_json, date_generated 
FROM 
    invoices as i 
LEFT JOIN 
    csi_tax_recv as c 
ON 
    c.invoice_number = i.id 
WHERE 
    DATE_FORMAT(date_generated,'%Y-%m') < DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m') 
AND 
    DATE_FORMAT(date_generated,'%Y-%m') >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 12 MONTH,'%Y-%m') 
GROUP BY  date_generated
    ORDER BY 
        date_generated
```

Looking over your query, I would normally say group on everything before the aggregate, but in this case, I'm not sure it makes sense. So group by what you order by (date_generated_) will group them on the associated date of invoice.

Answer (score 0):

As Vyskol mentioned in his comment I'm also sure you need to use a group by clause with all fields not used in an aggregate function.

Try this, hope this works:

```
SELECT
    i.tollfree_json,
    i.date_generated,
    SUM(i.invoice_amount + i.late_fee + c.tax) AS amount

FROM
    invoices as i JOIN csi_tax_recv as c ON i.id = c.invoice_number

WHERE
    DATE_FORMAT(date_generated,'%Y-%m') < DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m')
AND
    DATE_FORMAT(date_generated,'%Y-%m') >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 12 MONTH,'%Y-%m')

GROUP BY
    i.tollfree_json,
    i.date_generated

ORDER BY
    i.date_generated
```